# Understanding how CompletableFuture executing tasks parallelly?

Tags: java, multithreading

Assuming I've 4 core processor and declared the pool size is 5. My question is more of method chaining in `CompletableFuture` especially in asynchronous mode.

Since each step is operating on the result of previous step, what is the benefit of using async in this case? After all its a sequential execution in different thread possibly. Please clarify.

```
    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<EmployeeDTO> employees = mapper.readValue(Test1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("employees.json"), new TypeReference<List<EmployeeDTO>>() {
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> voidCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {

        System.out.println("Iteration 1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return employees.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getAge() > 25).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }, executor).thenApplyAsync((ageGreaterThan25) -> {

        System.out.println("Iteration 2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return ageGreaterThan25.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getGender().equals("female")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }, executor).thenApplyAsync((femalesAgeGreaterThan25) -> {

        System.out.println("Iteration 3: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return femalesAgeGreaterThan25.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getSalary() < 2000).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }, executor).thenApplyAsync((femalesAgeGreaterThan25EarningLess) -> {

        System.out.println("Iteration 4: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return femalesAgeGreaterThan25EarningLess.stream().filter(employee -> employee.getJob_title().equals("Machine Learning Engineer")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }, executor).thenAcceptAsync((femalesAgeGreaterThan25EarningLessML) -> {

        System.out.println("Iteration 5: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        femalesAgeGreaterThan25EarningLessML.forEach(employee -> {
            System.out.println("Increment salary by 5%");
            employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary() * 0.05);
        });
    }, executor);

    voidCompletableFuture.get();
```

Comment: Yes, async and completable futures probably provide absolutely no benefit here.

Comment: Assuming you only run one of these tasks at the same time, that's true. If you run many in parallel on the same executor, there could be benefits.